# How to fix the position change issue in Expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am trying to figure out how to fix the position change issue in Expandable listview. I have a image view consist of two icon basically for marking favourite and unfavourite. When i set onclick listner of imageview present in expandable listview adapter in below method

```
 @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.myfav, parent, false);

        }

final ImageView         favourite_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favourite_icon);
  favourite_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition).findViewById(R.id.favourite_icon);


            imageView.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.datedisplay),android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
}});
```

Position is coming wrong and some other item icon color is getting changed. When i scroll in this lisview the setted icon tint is getting changed automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be this:

```
        expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition)
```

Using the group index on the child list, that will cause problems.

Comment: expandableListView.getChildAt(groupPosition) is giving wrong index. For e.g when i click on first item last item color is changing and when i scroll the last item set color also resetted